# SQL execute string issue with National language character?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, database-design

i have a simple sp in sql as bellow :

```
    alter proc sptest(@val nvarchar(30))
    as

    select COUNT(*) from AAtable
    where name =  @val
```

as i call this sp with @val = 'مریم', it works well and returns value. 
but when i change it like this :

```
    alter proc sptest(@val nvarchar(30))
    as
    declare @q nvarchar(max)
    set @q = 'select COUNT(*) from AAtable where name = ' + @val

    Execute(@q)
```

and call it with the same @val, it converts @val value to "?" and returns error. i should say that @val comes from a string parameter in c#. as i know .net convert string to nvarchar parameter form sql. anyway i can not add N before @val.
and also i HAVE to make a string query and execute it so i can not change it to the first code too.

if i do this : set @q = 'select COUNT(*) from AAtable where name = N''' + @val + ''''     it does not work too.

why execute string makes my nvarchar parameter to "?" !?

Answer (score 0):

Add the N in front of your text, so it is an NVARCHAR literal, not a VARCHAR, like this: `N'My Text'`

Comment: as i said @val comes from C#, and i can not add N before it. and also c# do it automatically.

Comment: if i do this : set @q = 'select COUNT(*) from AAtable where name = N''' + @val + ''''     it does not work too.

Comment: In your dynamic sql literal, you have to add the N. Change this `set @q = 'select COUNT(*) from AAtable where name = ' + @val` to this set @q = N'select COUNT(*) from AAtable where name = ' + @val

Comment: it works when i try to use that character in a sql window. what does your data access code in C# look like? are you explicity declaring a datatype on a parameter?

Comment: public int Getest(string Value)
        {
            using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
            {
                var item = ctx.ExecuteScalar<int>(System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sptest", Value);
                return item;
            }
        }    Value parameter set from a textbox.text.

Comment: i've tried it in sql windows too, it still converts to "?" ! i use SQL 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Try marking the first string of your concatenation operation as explicit Unicode:

```
set @q = N'select COUNT(*) from AAtable where name = ' + @val
```

This should keep your `@val` in Unicode as well.

Comment: doesn't work! still returns this : select COUNT(*) from AAtable where name = '????'

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER proc sptest(@val nvarchar(30))
AS
    DECLARE @retval INT
    DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
    DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

    SET @SQLString =
         N'select @retvalOUT  = COUNT(*) from AAtable where name = @Name';
    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@Name varchar(30), retvalOUT int OUTPUT';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,
                          @Name  = @val,
                          @retvalOUT=@retval OUTPUT;
    SELECT @retval;
```

Comment: it returns nothing, not a value nor error. How does @ParmDefinition supposed to work and assign to @name?